# Jquery Boxy , Show one Dialog at a time

Tags: jquery, boxy

Im using [Boxy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/). I'm looking for inbuild function to open a One Dialog at a time. When I click on the button, Boxy Dialog will apper. When I again Clicked on the button, One more Same Dialog apper. I want to keep modal : false because of some reasons. I don't want to unbind the click event from element for every Dialog. it's ugly.

HTML

```
<a onClick='cube.edit()'>Edit</a>
```

Jquery

```
cube :
{
   edit : function()
   {
          // Open Boxy Dialog 
          edit_box = new Boxy("something",{ title : 'edit', modal : false });

   }

}
```

Comment: please share your HTML..

Comment: I need inbuild function from BOXY only.